# template with enum specialization

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have a template which takes as specialization an enum class (note the different initializations of enum), and I would like to be able to compare two different enums

```
enum choiceA {One, Two, Three};
typedef enum  {Four, Five, Six} choiceB;

template<typename S>
void f(S choice, int& x)
{
if (choice == One || choice == Four) { x = SomeWhateverIntegerValue;}
else if(choice = Five) {x = AnOtherWhateverIntegerValue;}
else {x = OtherIntegerValue;}
}
```

so that

```
int x = 0;
f<choiceA>(One, x);
```

works as intended.

Comment: just define regular function: `void f(choiceA choice, int& x)`. Also note you can't compare to `One` and to `Four` at the same time, those are different types.

Comment: do you want to parametrize `f` on the type of the enum or on values of one enum type? I have the impression that you are confusing the two or perhaps want a mix of both

Comment: *"an enum class"*. Both are regular (old) `enum`. `enum class choiceC {Seven};` would be `enum class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you have two enum types for the same enumeration is odd. I would fix that design first.

Anyway to strictly answer your question you don't need templates here. A simple overload would suffice:

```
void f(choiceA choice, int& x)
{
    if (choice == One)
    {
        x = SomeWhateverIntegerValue;
    }
    else
    {
        x = OtherIntegerValue;
    }
}

void f(choiceB choice, int& x)
{
    if (choice == Four)
    {
        x = SomeWhateverIntegerValue;
    } else if(choice == Five)
    {
        x = AnOtherWhateverIntegerValue;
    }
    else
    {
        x = OtherIntegerValue;
    }
}
```

---

As a side note avoid the C style `typedef enum/class { ... } Name;`.

Also take care `if(choice = Five)` you have a dangerous typo. It should be `==`. Enable compiler warnings, most modern compilers warn about this.